# What is the percentage of each track coming up when vs, random is selected?

Tags: mario-kart-8-deluxe

In Mario Kart 8 Deluxe when you select VS mode there is an option to have the game choose random tracks for you to race. Some of the tracks seem to come up more often then others so I want to know what the percentage of each track coming up is. Are they all equal? Or do some tracks like “Big Blue” have a smaller percentage?

Comment: I see Big Blue a lot, so it’s probably random, but I’m not 100%, which is why I’m not posting an answer.